# Three-way Linq list intersection plus nulls in one list

Tags: c#, linq

I have three lists A, B, and C of type `MyObject`. I need to get a list of the intersection between A, B and C based on a common Key:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
}

  var listA = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject("1"),
            new MyObject("2")
        };

        var listB = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject("1"),
            new MyObject("2"),
            new MyObject("3")
        };

        var listC = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject("1"),
            new MyObject("2"),
            new MyObject("3")
        };

        var query = (from b in listB
            join c in listC on b.Key equals c.Key
            join a in listA on c.Key equals a.Key
            select new { a, b, c}
        );

        var result = query.ToList();
```

That works fine, it returns a list like this:

```
[0]: {a.Key = 1, b.Key = 1, c.Key = 1}
[1]: {a.Key = 2, b.Key = 2, c.Key = 2}
```

Now, what I need is the intersection between b and c but including nulls for the non-matching a's:

```
[0]: {a.Key = 1, b.Key = 1, c.Key = 1}
[1]: {a.Key = 2, b.Key = 2, c.Key = 2}
[2]: {null, b.Key = 3, c.Key = 3}
```

I do not want to include null b's or c's. Only null a's. I tried doing it like a Left Outer Join by using `DefaultIfEmpty()` extension method but didn't work. Any suggestions on how I should modify my query above to get the expected results?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a "left join" for `a`:

```
    var query = (from b in listB
        join c in listC on b.Key equals c.Key
        join a in listA on c.Key equals a.Key into ca  // this will include c's with no matching a's.
        from ac in ca.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { a = ac, b, c}    // ac will be null if no a is found
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @DStanley. The query as you posted threw a compilation error but I changed it to this: `            var query = (from b in listB
                         join c in listC on b.Key equals c.Key
                         join a in listA on c.Key equals a.Key into ca  // this will include c's with no matching a's.
                         from ac in ca.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { a = ac, b, c }    // ac will be null if no a is found
                );` and it worked.

Comment: I was also trying to figure this out and got an error in the part `ac.a`, but a really nice solution +1

Comment: @AdolfoPerez OK I have amended my answer.